# How to make a PDF.js viewer scroll to matches in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I'm trying to use the pdf_viewer from pdfjs-dist (2.2.228) from within my react application. What I need to do is render the pdf and then programatically search for terms, scroll to the first match and then have the ability to scroll to the next and the next and so on. This is pretty-much the functionality of the web pdf_viewer but I need to build and integrate this into my app without the header from the web viewer.

I've managed to get the rendering to work and also the ability to search for terms in the text layer on demand. However, unlike the web viewer it doesn't scroll to the first hit and I can't figure out how to then make it scroll to further hits.

here's where I have got to:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import * as pdfWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker'
import PdfJsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
import 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css';
import * as pdfjsViewer from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer';

class ViewPdf extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const viewId = searchParams.get('id');
    this.state = {viewId:viewId};

    this.viewerContainer = React.createRef();
    this.viewer = React.createRef();

    this.pdfLinkService = new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService();

    this.pdfFindController = new pdfjsViewer.PDFFindController({
        linkService: this.pdfLinkService,
    });
}

  componentDidMount() {

    const fileUrl = "https://localhost:10101/<<my-pdf-file>>";

    let container = this.viewerContainer.current;
    let viewer = this.viewer.current;

    PdfJsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfWorker;
    PdfJsLib.getDocument(fileUrl).then((pdf) => {

        this.setState({numPages: pdf.numPages});

        this.pdfViewer = new pdfjsViewer.PDFViewer({
            container,
            viewer,
            linkService: this.pdfLinkService,
            findController: this.pdfFindController
        });

        this.pdfLinkService.setViewer(this.pdfViewer);

        this.pdfViewer.setDocument(pdf);
        this.pdfLinkService.setDocument(pdf, null);

        this.pdfLinkService.setViewer(this.pdfViewer);

    });
}

search=(terms) => {
    this.pdfFindController.executeCommand('find',{
        caseSensitive: false,
        highlightAll: true,
        scrollMatches: true,
        phraseSearch: true,
        findPrevious: true,
        query: terms
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                onClick={(e) =>this.search("obligations")}
            >
                Search
            </Button>
            <div id="viewerContainer" ref={this.viewerContainer}>
                <div id="viewer" ref={this.viewer} className="pdfViewer"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ViewPdf;
```

I've tried react-pdf and got that working but the search functionality in there isn't good enough for what I need. This is very close but I could really do with some pointers on how to get the rendered output to scroll programatically.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to complete this? Can you help me if you did compete. I found another question but he has a start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913361/react-and-pdf-js-changing-page-doesnt-work-when-i-render-whole-document

Comment: nope - I moved to use the pdftron viewer instead in the end.